# window.onerror does not fires in my firefox add-on (page-mod API)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing a Firefox extension (add-on) using API page-mod to call a content-script.

In the content script, Im using window.onerror to record js errors when the page loads. The content-script executes correctly but window.onerror never triggers yet there are js errors in the Page that loads (I have verified that windows.onerror can capture the errors).

Here is a simplified version of the code:

lib/main.js

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptFile: "./simple_script.js"
});
```

data/simple_script.js

```
window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
    window.alert(errorMsg, url, lineNumber);
}
```

I'm testing with Firefox 34.0.5

Any idea why the window.onerror does not fires when the page load and there are js errors on the page ?

Comment: Try `window.error = function() [ }`

Answer (score 1):

You need ensure that your `window.onerror` be a at the top of your code, if any error was thrown before the `window.onerror` was declared it will never be catch.

Comment: It is indeed at the top of the code. but it does not trigger